# Is the Sausage Party's ending a tribute to Jodorowsky's Holy Mountain?

Tags: reference, sausage-party, the-holy-mountain

At the end of [Sausage Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sausage_Party) the "guru" character of the movie reveals to the main characters that everything that is happened during the movie is fiction (and that they are stereotypically created in the image of some famous actors). This kind of breaking of the fourth wall remembers me the last scene of [Holy Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holy_Mountain_(1973_film)).

Is there any correlation or is it just a coincidence? Is that a tribute?

Comment: Considering how lowbrow *Sausage Party* is, I'd quite honestly be *astounded* if the ending was a reference to something like Jodorowsky.